# PHP Black Jack game; updating display

Tags: php, session, savestate, blackjack

my first question on stackOverflow! Have read tons of useful tidbits on here, but haven't been able to find a useful answer to the following question.

I've written a blackjack game in PHP as a learning experience in OO PHP. I have one main object which contains the details of all the cards and the game state, I serialize this and save it to a file however this will cause conflicts when more than one person is playing at the same time. I've looked into sessions and saving this data there, but wonder if I need to generate special session id's etc. How do I

Also, there might be a good solution to this problem I haven't considered. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you tested multiple number of people playing the game? Did you just open a new tab in a browser and connect to the same site? Or did 2 people in different computers play the game?

Comment: The manual gives [several examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.php) of how to use sessions.  I'd start with one of those examples, and expand as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is use a database for this matter. You shouldn't use sessions to save the game state since it will require all players of the game to have the same data, thus, you will need to duplicate every player's data and save it in the other player's session.

Use sessions to authenticate and know who is who when you're trying to access data from your database

Comment: @user482594: I tested by having two browsers open assuming that when I connected to the server it would give each browser a unique ID which it could track through session id's.  I was hoping that there was a way to tie a unique session id to session data stored about each connected user. But I guess that's unlikely!

Comment: I thought that sessions recorded a unique bit of information for each logged in user, so surely using the session_id as the session name would make sense. i.e. 
'code'
$mySession_id = session_id();
$mySaveState = serialize($this->card_pack);
$_SESSION['$mySession_id'] = $mySaveState;

This should save the data from my card_pack object under the session Id name for this specific user and not anyone else. Or am I totally misunderstanding how sessions work?

Cheers